# Can we assign a pig relation to set of values, and is there an alternative?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-pig-grunt

```
%describe DATA '1,2,3'; 
LOAD DATA as (f1,f2,f3) USING PigStorage(');
```

or is it possible to convert a datatype to Pig relation (map datatype to Pig relation)?

Bag of tuples with static values assigned to variable and loading this bag of tuples as Pig relation.

Basically, I cannot load data as I do not have it as a file. But need to join on top of some static data as above '1,2,3'.